# codeigniter - store post data in session and display in view

Tags: codeigniter, session, variables, post

I have a codeigniter form that users populate. on submission the inputs are posted to an array. this array is then displayed on the new view that is loaded as variables.

My issue is that if I refresh the view for whatever reason, those posts are lost and the new view cant display the variables.

How can I store the posted array as a session value and then how do I access the session variables.

So my controller is:

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
  {
    $data = array(
    'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
    'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
    'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom')
       );

    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
  }
```

on `new_blank_order_lines` I can display the variables with `echo $customer`

now if I refresh the view `new_blank_order_lines`, the view is reloaded and the post variables lost. So I want to store the $data array as a session so it is available even after a page reload / refresh.

Any advice?

I am thinking something like:

```
    function new_blank_order_lines() 
      {
        $data = array(
        'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
        'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
        'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom')
           );

        $this->session->$data

        $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
      }
```

this obviously does not work? if it does work how do I echo out the value of the variable?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you do with the information that the user submit to the form? Is it not saved to a database or similar? If that is the case then why dont you retrieve the data from there?

If you just want to be able to whow the data temporarily you could use the session variables like in your last example, but with a few modifications:

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
  {
    $data = array(
    'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
    'period' =>$this->input->post('period'),
    'buom' =>$this->input->post('buom')
       );

    $this->session->set_userdata($data);

    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$this->session->all_userdata());
  }
```

[See user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not writing it to a database just yet, only after the next form is completed. so just want to show it temporarily. I changed my syntax for the session as you suggested above and it work when the page is loaded for the first time. if however I refresh the page, the session variables are also lost? is this something to do with controller? perhaps it is reloading the array with blank post variables? How can I do an if statement to see if the session has been set? or am I totally on the wrong track here? thanks

Comment: Yes you are, $this->input->post() returns FALSE if the post variables are not set.  so do this check first: 

    if ($this->input->post()){
        set data here

Answer (score 0):

```
$projectID = $this->input->post('projectID');
if($projectID!=''){
    $this->session->set_userdata('projectID', $projectID);
}
```

post Data will not expire while reloading use this code